# JS: What is the difference between these ternary operators in this example

Tags: javascript

I am looking at a `reduce` example and don't quite understand what `(tally[fruit] || 0) + 1 ;` is doing.  I would have wrote it as `tally[fruit] = !!tally[fruit] ? 0 : 1 ;` .  Is that the same thing it's trying to do?

```
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig' ];

const count = fruitBasket.reduce( (tally, fruit) => {
  tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1 ;
  return tally;
} , {})

count // { banana: 2, cherry: 3, orange: 3, apple: 2, fig: 1 }
```

Comment: `(tally[fruit] || 0) + 1` evaluates to `1` if `tally[fruit]` is "falsey" or `tally[fruit]+1` otherwise, which is not the same as `!!tally[fruit] ? 0 : 1 ` which evaluates to `1` if `tally[fruit]` is "falsey" or `0` otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codes are not equivalent.

Doing

```
tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1 ;
```

will result in each `fruit` being counted up on the object. For example, iterating over `['a', 'b', 'b']`, starting with the empty object:

```
tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1;
tally.a = (tally.a || 0) + 1;
tally.a = (0) + 1;
tally.a = 1;
```

```
tally.b = (tally.b || 0) + 1;
tally.b = (0) + 1;
tally.b = 1;
```

```
tally.b = (tally.b || 0) + 1;
tally.b = (1) + 1;
tally.b = 2;
```

resulting in `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`.

The other code does something pretty different:

```
tally[fruit] = !!tally[fruit] ? 0 : 1;
```

Since `tally[fruit]` always starts out `undefined`, the `1` branch will be entered, but then on further iterations over the same fruit, since `1` is truthy, the `0` branch will still be entered. It'll toggle between 0 and 1. You'd get `{ a: 1, b: 0 }`. Probably not desirable.

```js
const count = ['a', 'b', 'b'].reduce( (tally, fruit) => {
  tally[fruit] = !!tally[fruit] ? 0 : 1 ;
  return tally;
} , {})
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

What it is doing is the order of evaluation.the first part evaluated is the one with parentheses so first it will be
either the number that is already in your accumulator for instance in the case when that fruit has already been counted. or a 0 when it is the first time the fruit is encountered to allow the adding operation to succeed.

below are some examples as to why the grouping operator is needed:

```js
let fruities={banana:5};

const goodIncrementer = (fruities,fruitName) => (fruities[fruitName]||0)+1;

const badIncrementer = (fruities,fruitName) => fruities[fruitName]||0+1;

console.log("goodie",goodIncrementer(fruities,"banana"))
console.log("baddie",badIncrementer(fruities,"banana"))
```

Comment: Actually the left hand side has precedence even without the parenthesis. So `false || 0 + 1` returns `1` as well.

Comment: True, it is probably for readabilty as we tend to think of PEMDAS. And my statement is still correct the first part evaluated is the one in parentheses.

Comment: Well, no, the first part of the expression is left of `||` so thats why it gets evaluated first. The parenthesis, in this example at least. as you mention, are for readability. It could equally be `1 + (x || 0)`

Comment: I think you are getting caught up in use of vocabulary. here is some information as to what I was trying to describe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping

Comment: We are on the same page with "order of operations" @JayGarzo. However, in this case, the `||` operator as @Nick mentions as comment of OP's question, evaluates the left hand expression of said operator first. Now of course if you use parenthesis, the order rules still applies. Was saying the parenthesis in the example given were for readability, like you mentioned. .... You seemed to suggest that the return value was *because* of the parenthesis?

Comment: Its interesting now because I ran a little test and my result contradicts it. can you explain this:  let a=5;               

when i run a||1+1 i get 5 then I run (a||1)+1 get 
6
run a||1+1
get 5
did this in node shell

Comment: Ok. I stand corrected. But in OP's example it was `x || 0 + 1`. So the zero kind of makes the parenthesis not matter, agreed?

Comment: In other words, using the OP's context, (and no one else's), `(x || 0 ) + 1` is logically equivalent to `x || 0 + 1`. I think.

Comment: please see my edited answer for an example

Comment: Ok. You are correct @JayGarzon. I am wrong. Did some tests. I got different results between parenthesis and no parenthesis even with keeping to context of having `0` on right side.

Comment: @GetSet no worries it can get confusing. All that matters is we learn more everyday

Answer (score 0):

`tally[fruit] || 0` is just a shorthand version of preventing undefined value from creeping into your logic flow.

What this code does is that , it checks if `tally[fruit]` is defined, which means checking if `tally` object has that fruit as key or not. If key exist, then use the value otherwise, default to 0

In normal syntax , this code would do the exact same thing

```
if( tally[fruit] ) {
   tally[fruit] = tally[fruit] + 1;
}else {
   tally[fruit] = 1;
}
```